# Pagination in the event search API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am performing a rest call to facebooks search API using type=event

e.x.

```
search?fields=id,name,picture,owner,description,start_time,end_time,location,venue,updated_time,ticket_uri&q=concert&type=event
```

I have looked through the documentation and still have a few questions about specific pagination behavior of the event search API.

1. If I used a broad search term like "ma" and keep querying the pagination ['next'] URL would I cycle through all facebook events starting with "ma"? Does the pagination array give any indication when there are no more results to return?.
2. Do these searches include past events? If so is it possible to eliminate past events using the "since" parameter?
3. What is the maximum for the limit parameter?

Update:

As far as I can tell the number of pages you can get from a facebook search is limited to 500. This includes pages that can be accessed via pagination. In other words a query with limit >=500 will not return a pagination url, likewise a query with limit 250 will only return one pages worth of pagination.

Comment: Here is the page to help you with facbook pagination and the graph API [Facebook Developers Api Pagination Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/pagination/)

Answer (score 0):

1. You will "next page" until the count of results comes less then the limit
2. I'm not sure if that is possible using a simple Graph Request. Maybe using FQL
3. I don't know exactly. But i used a 2000 limit one day. And it worked.

Other doubts you can get answers testing your resquests with this tool

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Comment: Hi Joao, thanks for your response. Regarding answer "1" it is my understanding that graph requests 'hide' responses that that aren't 'visible' such as private events and for that reason queries will come back with fewer entries than than the limit number even if you aren't on the final page, is there any other indication when the final page has been reached? Regarding answer "2" I don't believe FQL is a viable option because none of the time fields on an event are indexable and therefore cannot be used in an FQL Where clause, am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

I am also doing the same thing like you. I am collecting public post using graph search api.

1. When there are no results available or you reach max limit pagination section will not be there in response. So you can always check for paging is there in json response or not something like this.

   NextResult = DeserJsonFBResponce.paging != null ? DeserJsonFBResponce.paging.next : string.Empty;
2. I am not so sure about this with events but for public post i am able to eliminate post using science and until parameters.
3. Maximum for the limit parameter is 2000 per get request.